# how to get specific row and columns from excel using pandas without losing format?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a an excel file that I need to extract specific rows and columns. Here is a sample file:

[image]

I want to get all rows from 0 - 2. Here is how I'm extracting it using **Pandas**:

```
headers = pd.read_excel(sample_file, nrows=2)
headers.to_excel(id_file + 'header.xlsx', index=False)
```

But above code removes the format of the rows. Is there any way to retain the format? Appreciate the advise.

Comment: Nope, not really.

Comment: you can use CSS2.2 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel